# How to change the menu icon of mate desktop menu applet?

Tags: icons, customization, menu, mate

I am using the Mate Desktop Environment 1.4.1 and having a Mate-Menu applet in the bottom panel:

> Shutdown *[ICON]* Applications Places System

See this screenshot:

[image: Mate Desktop Environment]

Is there any way to change or remove the *[ICON]* on the left of the Applications menu?

Where does MATE take this from? I noticed the icon changes when using different icon-themes but I don't understand how to customize only this single icon.

Comment: What icon? Shut down or Gentoo? :)

Comment: Sorry: the black-ish Gentoo icon, yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change icon on MATE main menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183025/change-icon-on-mate-main-menu)

Answer (score 1):

It is theme dependent. For example, if you are using AwokenDark icons, you can check which icon the start-here symbolic icon points to, with

```
$ ls -l ~/.icons/AwOkenDark/clear/24x24/places/start-here.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 35 nov 24 08:37 /home/user/.icons/AwOkenDark/clear/24x24
/places/start-here.png -> ../start-here/start-here-gentoo3.png
```

you can change the symbolic link to point to another image from the start-here directory in the theme, for example start-here-ubuntu1.png.