# Change icon on MATE main menu

Tags: icons, mate, customization, ubuntu-mate, applet

How can I change the default logo icon to a custom icon by the applications menu in Ubuntu MATE without changing the theme?

[image: screenshot combo with this icon on MATE main menu]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately for this menu it is only possible to do manually with the dconf-editor.

1. install dconf-editor
   `sudo apt install dconf-editor`
2. go to  `org > mate > panel > menubar`
3. change default icon-name to your new icon name

if you want to have a custom icon, copy the .svg image to /usr/share/icons/apps/image.svg
replace image with the image title of course...

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-i-can-change-main-menu-icon/9884/3

PS: Using Manjaro you simply have to put your prefered icon to `~/.icons/logo-manjaro.svg`

PSS: I found the name of the menu's icon using [Gtk Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Inspector)

Comment: This used to work for me  (with version 3.36.7)- but now there seems to be a new version of dconf editor (3.38.3) and in the org-mate-panel menu there are only the submenus GEneral OBJECTS TOPLEVELS and no possibility to edit the icon of the MAIN MENU as an object,,,

Answer (score 1):

Use gsettings command for a one-line solution.

To change the icon named foo:

```
gsettings set org.mate.panel.menubar icon-name 'foo'
```

The string within single quotes refers to the icon name of any theme that has been installed properly in `/usr/share/icons` and `~/.local/share/icons` directories. To find out icon names that are available by default, refer to [the Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html).

For example, replace 'string' with 'user-bookmarks' to show the bookmark icon on the main menu. The bookmark icon may appear as a yellow star, a red heart, or a folder with star emboss, depending on which icon theme is used.

Unfortunately, MATE main menu has no easy way to use a custom icon without changing the system-wide theme. The MATE main menu will look for the icon name of *currently used theme* and that makes difficult to use a single custom icon.

To restore the icon to default:

```
gsettings reset org.mate.panel.menubar icon-name
```

Note that the question is specific to the MATE main menu applet. A different menu applet--the advanced MATE menu--uses a different schema, or even better, already have an option to change the default icon from the preferences.

Tested in Ubuntu MATE 18.04 (MATE 1.20)