# Change Icon of Main Menu in Panel (Mate)

Tags: icons, mate-panel

I already was able to change the icon of the Main Menu in the panel of Mate using these suggestions

[Change icon on MATE main menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183025/change-icon-on-mate-main-menu)

Yesterday, suddenly menu was gone, I fixed it and eanted to assign "my" icon again, doing the same procedure. This time it did not work...

I started dconf-editor

> mate > panel > menubar add my requested file name without and with or without path: Mein Menu icon does not change (that is the one with the little arrow on top). I use the Numix Circle Icon set, and want to have an icon from the very same set. Do not understand, because i did it once, and it worked

To the suggestion below saying: "if you want to have a custom icon, copy the .svg image to /usr/share/icons/apps/image.svg replace image with the image title of course..."

I do not have such a path... /usr/share/icons/apps... Thanks for any help

B.

Answer (score 0):

I intended to change the provides icon for the Main Menu applet in the Mate-Panel.
This is how I succeeded:
I opened dconf-editor
then: /org/mate/panel/objects

- Objects - staying for each applet in the panel - are numbered, some of them can be identified immediately by the line in "custom-id", but most  of them are not. I have about 15 objects there, each standing for an applet on may panel in Mate.
  I identified the Main Menu applet (in my case #12) by switching the "has-arrow' line on/off
- then I unlocked  "custom icon"
- and in a next step I specified the location of the icon I wanted want to use in "custom icon"

Hope this clearer now. By this procedure one can change anyIcon in the startin applets in the panel
B.